# Composing `Future` result in Play Framework with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, monads

I am trying to write a Play Framework asynchronous Action for the following URL:

```
POST /users/:userId/items
```

My database calls all return `Future[...]`, where `...` is `Option[A]` for `find` methods and `Option[Id]` for create methods.

I would like to check for the existence of the userId before trying to create the new item. I have a method `Users.findById(userId)` that returns a `Future[Option[User]]`. The result is `Some(User)` if the user exists and `None` if not. `Items.create()` also returns a `Future[Option[itemId]]`.

I am trying to compose something using `for`:

```
for {
  user <- Users.findById(userId)
  if user.isDefined
} yield {
  Items.create(...) map { itemId => Ok(itemId) } getOrElse NotFound
}
```

I would like to return `Ok(itemId)` if the item is successfully created. I'm not sure how to handle the error case. I would like to return `NotFound` if either the userId is invalid or the item cannot be created (maybe a field conflicts with a unique value already in the database).

I'm not sure what to put after the `for` structure. I tried `getOrElse`, but that does not compile, since `Future` does not have a `getOrElse` method.

Ideally, I can handle URLs containing several ids to check, e.g.:

```
PUT /users/:userId/foo/:fooId/bar/:barId
```

and confirm that `userId`, `fooId`, and `barId` are all valid before doing the update. All of those calls (`Users.findById`, `Foo.findById`, and `Bar.findById`) will return `Future[Option[A]]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's that double-nesting (`Future` of `Option`) that seems to get people every time.  Things become a lot easier if you can flatten stuff out first.

In this case, `Future` already has a way of representing an error condition, it can wrap an `Exception` as well as a success value, that's something you can use...

```
// making this a Singleton avoids the cost of building a stack trace,
// which only happens when an Exception is constructed (not when it's thrown)
object NotFoundException extends RuntimeException("Empty Option")

// The map operation will trap any thrown exception and fail the Future
def squish[T](x: Future[Option[T]]) =
  x map { _.getOrElse(throw NotFoundException) }
```

It's now a lot easier to use those squished results in a comprehension:

```
val result = for {
  user <- squish(Users findById userId)
  itemId <- squish(Items.create(user, ...))
} yield {
  Ok(itemId)
} recover {
  case NotFoundException => NotFound
}
```

Which will, of course, evaluate to a Future.  This is async programming, after all :)

Any exceptions other than `NotFoundException` will still be exposed.

Comment: Tossing around exceptions like this isn't *entirely* elegant, but it's about as clean as you can get using Scala out-of-the-box and not using scalaz or building your own library of monad transformers